# Async load font not fulfilling promise in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, async-await, promise, preload

Background: I have written a preloader for various file types for the retro game engine I am building in JavaScript. I have issues with loading fonts with Firefox (116.0b1, issue was present in older versions too).

The relevant functions are:

```
async function loadAllFonts(fonts = LoadFonts) {
        if (!fonts) return;
        console.log(`%c ...loading ${fonts.length} fonts`, ENGINE.CSS);
        ENGINE.LOAD.HMFonts = fonts.length;
        if (ENGINE.LOAD.HMFonts) appendCanvas("Fonts");
        try {
          const fontPromises = fonts.map(font => loadFont(font));
          const loadedFonts = await Promise.all(fontPromises);
          loadedFonts.forEach(font => document.fonts.add(font));
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error loading fonts: ${error}`);
          return false;
        }
      }
```

And:

```
async function loadFont(srcData, dir = ENGINE.FONT_SOURCE) {
        try {
          const fontSource = dir + srcData.srcName;
          const url = `url(${fontSource})`;
          const temp = new FontFace(srcData.name, url);
          const font = await temp.load();
          ENGINE.LOAD.Fonts++;
          ENGINE.drawLoadingGraph("Fonts");
          return font;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(`Error loading font: ${srcData.srcName}`, error);
        }
      }
```

I wanted to assure that fonts are loaded, before game starts. Fonts are also declared in CSS and HTML part also requires that font. CSS (relevant part):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Moria';
    src:url("/Fonts/MoriaCitadel.ttf");
    font-display: swap;
}
```

This worked without exception with Crome (114.0.5735.199 or earlier).

In Firefox, I used absolute links in the CSS in the beginning (oversight) and relative links in JS part, and I always encountered that `Promise` of this font was never fulfilled on first try, it only worked after it was already in cache, after refreshing the page. Loading of the font which was triggered by HTML/CSS (before JS) resulted in NS_BINDING_ABORTED. Font loading triggered by this JS preloader, loaded in the background, without fulfilling the `Promise`. I could reproduce the issue by force reloading (CTRL-SHIFT-R) the page. Undesired behaviour was consistent on `localhost` and on production server. Everything worked after 'normal' refresh when font is already in the cache.

When I changed links in CSS from absolute to relative. It started to work also in Firefox, but only on `localhost`. On production server, behaviour remained the same (but without the NS_BINDING_ABORTED message): `Promise` was not fulfilled, preloader remained waiting for it.
Checking the network shows that font has been loaded. It always is ...

Refreshing the page (without clearing the cache) resolves the issue, but that is not good enough.

My short term solution is to actually don't wait for the `Promise` as with the amount of data to be loaded, font has plenty of time to load, and preloaders of other types behave correctly:

```
async function loadFont(srcData, dir = ENGINE.FONT_SOURCE) {
        try {
          const fontSource = dir + srcData.srcName;
          const url = `url(${fontSource})`;
          const temp = new FontFace(srcData.name, url);
          //const font = await temp.load();                       //firefox has issue with this             
          ENGINE.LOAD.Fonts++;
          ENGINE.drawLoadingGraph("Fonts");
          //return font;
          return temp.load();                                     //ff fix, but not really waiting for font
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(`Error loading font: ${srcData.srcName}`, error);
        }
      }
```

This of course is only a temporary fix. Any ideas how to solve this generally to also work in Firefox?